# Magento 2 : Cart rule discount applies twice

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

Here is the cart rule
[image]

I am not sure why it is applying double discount on products
see
[image]

Comment: Can anybody please advice me if i am misunderstood the cart rule ?
I am not sure why it applies % amount twice ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: It seems like it taking as fixed amount. What discount it shows if you increase one more qty?

Comment: hello, let me check

Comment: Here it is https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/8171157?key=8d7fedb98c89203e0223054576f713ad

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try once by enabling this https://prnt.sc/12uakyb ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What does this do zealous web ?

Comment: It will discard the other rules to be apply on the same time. Will it work??

Comment: i am checking by using coupon, so i think their is no possibility that other rule can process